# Accessing last created row in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

How to access the row which has just been inserted into a DB with PHP/MySQL?

I have:

```
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO `jos_db`.`jos_sections` (`id`,  `name`) VALUES (NULL, \'foo\')';
    mysql_query($sql, $dbi);

    bar();
```

How do I access the new row in bar()?

Comment: A lot of things could be google-searched, but wouldn't you rather find it on stackoverflow? ;o)

Comment: Up-voted because I think it's a legitimate question that doesn't deserve the bad karma from a down-vote. Also: I agree with Jon, that just because it *can be googled*, doesn't mean it's contrary to the aim of Stackoverflow, which, as I recall, is something like 'to be the definitive programming questions-and-answers/solutions site on the internet.'

Comment: It's a good question, so "don't scold the newbies!" and is there an admin around who can consolidate the half dozen or so minor variations on this exact same question? Using mysql_insert_id() gets the id of the new row, assuming `id` is an autoincrement field.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you 'id' column is an auto-increment, you can use [mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) :

> Retrieves the ID generated for an
>   `AUTO_INCREMENT` column by the previous
>   `INSERT` query.

The example given in the manual looks like this :

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('mydb');

mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable (product) values ('kossu')");
printf("Last inserted record has id %d\n", mysql_insert_id());
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the last item inserted with mysql_insert_id()

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Answer (score 3):

Use  mysql_insert_id() function to select last row inserted in database.

```
SELECT rows from table where id = last_inserted_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the PHP function `mysql_insert_id()` will return the id of the last row you inserted.