# How to get the ID of the last inserted row in the table in MySql with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql="INSERT INTO tu_cla_facets VALUES(null,\"".addslashes($facet)."\",\"".addslashes($description)."\",\"".$parentId."\",\"\",\"".addslashes($leafFacet)."\",\"".addslashes($hidden)."\",\"\",'',NOW(),\"".$username."\",NOW(),\"".$username."\",\"\",\"\");";        
        $res=$this->con->query($sql);
```

This is the code of inserting, how to get the ID of this row? It's an auto-increment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing last created row in PHP/MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358781/accessing-last-created-row-in-php-mysql)

Comment: all the answer below should get -1, as using mysql_* function insteaf of mysqli_* function

Comment: I just realized that myself, non of them worked except one! But how did you know I was using mysqli?

Comment: farid mysql_insert_id() as other suggested. Keep in mind that if you are using permanent connection to your sql server and you have many users you'll get the wrong last id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not clear from your code which DB abstraction library you are using (if any.) It may have its own method for obtaining last inserted id.

Also, mysql_insert_id() will work only if you use standard mysql library. If you use mysqli, for example, this may work better:

```
$last_id = $this->con->insert_id;
```

Comment: This is the only one that worked! I didn't notice the difference if it's mysqli or not until you've mentioned. I am new to php and it's not my code

Answer (score 2):

Use the [mysql_insert_id()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) function

```
$id = mysql_insert_id();
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `$id = mysql_insert_id($con);` or `$id = $con->insert_id();` ?

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Answer (score 2):

mysql_insert_id returns the id of the last inserted record
[more info here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('mydb');

mysql_query("INSERT INTO mytable (product) values ('kossu')");
printf("Last inserted record has id %d\n", mysql_insert_id());
?>
```

Comment: note that the question is already using a different method of calling the query, so most of the code you've posted here is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Just call `mysql_insert_id()` after insertion.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do

```
SELECT last_insert_id();
```

in a seperate query, if whatever DB library you're doing doesn't have its own method for this (which generally just issue this query anyways). As long as you're using the same DB handle, you're guaranteed to get the ID of the last insertion opereration performed.

Answer (score -1):

well simple make a regular select order by id desc

something like this

`"SELECT * FROM tu_cla_facets ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1"`

the mysql_insert_id will only work if you during the script made an insert

edit: this will always get the last inserted row which in some rare cases but possible doesn't has to be the very row you just insert.

Comment: -1 because this would give the wrong answer if another insert has been made in the meanwhile (which is possible in a multi-user environment like a web site even if you call it right after the insert)

Comment: excuse me i just read the title and this will always get the last row's id...But as you said it may give the wrong id if you expect get the row id for the current insert as there is a possibility that other inserts are running in the meanwhile