# How to know the id (autoincrement) of the entry recently made to MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

my users fill a form who sends the data to a database (MySQL), and then redirects the users to a php script who renders the information recently addend by the user, but the render script need the id of data entered by the user, i need to POST this data from the form, any ideas?

This is the php code of the insertion:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `freedomshare`.`post` (`id`, `title`, `content`, `datetime`, `author`, `private`, `password`, `comments`, `qrcode`, `counter`, `editable`, `active`) VALUES (NULL, '" . addslashes($_POST['title']) . "', '" . addslashes($_POST['input']) . "', NOW(), '" . addslashes($_POST['author']) . "', $private,'" . addslashes($_POST['password']) . "', $comments, $qrcode, '0', $editable, '1');";
mysql_query($sql);
```

Is any way to know the value that **id** gets after executing this lines?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing last created row in PHP/MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358781/accessing-last-created-row-in-php-mysql)

Comment: Please search for existing questions/answers before you post a new question - this topic has already been covered in some detail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

You can use the php function mysql_insert_id
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `freedomshare`.`post` (`id`, `title`, `content`, `datetime`, `author`, `private`, `password`, `comments`, `qrcode`, `counter`, `editable`, `active`) VALUES (NULL, '" . addslashes($_POST['title']) . "', '" . addslashes($_POST['input']) . "', NOW(), '" . addslashes($_POST['author']) . "', $private,'" . addslashes($_POST['password']) . "', $comments, $qrcode, '0', $editable, '1');"; 
mysql_query($sql);
$id = mysql_insert_id();
```