# Get ID from MySQL INSERT

Tags: php, mysql, row

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: how to get last inserted ID of a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685860/php-how-to-get-last-inserted-id-of-a-table)

I am having a problem with my MySQL insert. I have an Id column that is  `AUTO_INCREMENT` and I run this code into that table:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tickets (Submitted, UNIXtime, Subject, Text, User, Priority, Status, Service) VALUES ('$date', '$UNIXtime', '$subject', '$text', '$userss', '$priority', '$status', '$service')");
```

It then inserts an Id number in that row. How would I get that ID number so I can echo it out for example `$id = (The ID number from that submit);
echo $id;`?

Thanks for the help. If you could, can you rewrite the code to make it work and post it so I know what to do?

Comment: @AdrianCornish I just wanted someone to also help rewrite my code in context

Comment: @Darayus - fair enough - but maybe then you should have phrased your question "How do I rewrite my got to use last insert id*" I am learning stackoverflow is now just for answer a question but providing historical answers to the "same" question

Comment: @AdrianCornish Did you read the last linke of my question? "If you could, can you rewrite the code"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [`mysql_insert_id()`](http://php.net/mysql_insert_id). This function will return the ID of the last query.

You could call it after running your query:

```
mysql_query( $insert_query );
echo "Last ID is " . mysql_insert_id();
```

Comment: How would I relate that to my code up there?

Comment: replace with the '(The ID number from that submit)'

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`mysql_insert_id`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) to get the last ID from the table. Note: You have to call `mysql_insert_id` right after the insert as it works only on the last executed query.

```
$id = mysql_insert_id();
```

Comment: I see what you mean. Is there a way to prevent that as I am expecting very high insertion rates.

Comment: I'll have to rephrase that as it wasn't entirely correct.

Comment: You also don't have to worry about concurrent requests, works as expected, a user will see the last ID from his own insert, ignoring other inserts which are made in parallel

Answer (score 2):

With `mysql_insert_id();`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html

```
//Example
$id = mysql_insert_id(); 
echo $id;
```

Answer (score 0):

[mysql_insert_id()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

Comment: Wow.. this is why I never post answers on this site anymore. In the time it took me to type in my answer 2 other answers of the same thing had already been posted...

Comment: Tim, just take your time to answer questions. Even if someone posts before you it doesn't mean that the answer is better or even correct.

Comment: try answering hard questions, no one will bother you there :)

Comment: @halfdan is absolutely correct. Write a great answer; you'll receive votes regardless of how quickly it was posted.

Comment: Ah.. I knew I was having deja vu, I answered this question a couple of years ago too.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358781/accessing-last-created-row-in-php-mysql/ :)

And yeah, the "write good answers" thing is right. I hate feeling rushed here, not sure why I do.. heh.