# How to get recently inserted auto-increment id from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table, named `war_engagement` which has an auto-increment id (named `w_e_id`) as primary key.
I am inserting records like this

```
//insertion in first table
$query = "INSERT INTO war_engagement (
                `attacker_user_id` ,
                `attacker_city_id` ,
                `attacker_mode` ,
                `result`
                )
                VALUES (
                '$_SESSION[user_id]',
                '$cur_city_id',
                'default',
                ''
                )";
$rs = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()." in query $query");
```

And if above query executes successfully then I want to insert this recently inserted auto-increment id (that is `w_e_id`) as foreign key into another table named `war_engagement_troops`

```
//if first record inserted successfully then insert second table
if($rs)
{
    echo "'".$sending_troop."' ,";
        $query = "INSERT INTO war_engagement_troops (
                    `w_e_id` ,
                    `quantity` ,
                    `expired`
                    )
                    VALUES (
                    '$recently_inserted_w_e_id',
                    '$quantity',
                    '$expired'
                    )";
    $rs = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()." in query $query");
    if(!$rs) echo $rs;
}
```

I want to get `w_e_id` (which is auto-increment) to assign it to `$recently_inserted_w_e_id`.

(I also used MAX(w_e_id) to retrieve maximum ID but it is not looking ideal way and can be mixed up in multiple users insertions).

Please give me some ideal solution to get recently inserted id/record.

Comment: Answering you edition at the bottom, mysql_insert_id, unlike your `SELECT MAX` approach, returns the ID inserted by **your connection**, not the last id inserted globally. So if you just ran an INSERT in your script, and then ran mysql_insert_id, you will always get the ID you just inserted, even if someone inserted something in the meantime

Comment: Thank you Ishamael. You realized me the issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing last created row in PHP/MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358781/accessing-last-created-row-in-php-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  mysql_insert_id() function to get last inserted id and then you can use that as foregin key for another table

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for mysql_insert_id() function. But I strongly recommend you to use PDO

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use MAX(w_e_id), Then after the INSERT statement you can use

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

We can make use of [mysql_insert_id()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-insert-id.html); function as well

It will look something like this

```
$query = "INSERT INTO war_engagement ( `w_e_id` , ...)  VALUES ( ...);
//if first record inserted successfully then insert second table
if($rs)
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO war_engagement_troops ( `id` ,  `w_e_id` , ...)  VALUES (  '', LAST_INSERT_ID(), ....)";
                   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use mysqli_insert_id() function or the mysqli::$insert_id property if you use the object-oriented style

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

If using PDO, use the method PDO::lastInsertId()

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Answer (score 1):

```
$recently_inserted_w_e_id = mysql_insert_id();
```

Answer (score -1):

SELECT TOP 1 w_e_id 
FROM war_engagement
Order By w_e_id desc